# ClassNotFoundException - org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around

Tags: java, spring

I see the below classnotfoundexception when I start my app. I have added my dependency tree as well. Please can you let me know what is causing this exception?

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   ... 19 common frames omitted

```
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka: -> 1.1.6.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.3.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.10.RELEASE
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.1.1
|         +--- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.3.0
|         \--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.2.6
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter: -> 1.5.6.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.6.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.7
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.7 -> 2.8.9
+--- com.kafka.test:txdb-connector:0.2.10
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.1.RELEASE -> 1.5.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.4.1.RELEASE -> 1.5.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.16
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.5.16
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    +--- com.oracle:ojdbc6:12.1.0.1
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.2.4.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE -> 4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.3.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.4.RELEASE -> 1.5.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:1.2.3.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:4.2.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:1.2.3.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:4.2.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.10.RELEASE
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 -> 2.8.7 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.10.RELEASE (*)
```

Comment: adding compile('org.springframework:spring-aspects') seems to resolve the issue

Comment: If that resolved your issue, you should add it as an answer. You can accept it after 48 hours.

Comment: Sure , will do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was resolved after adding the below listed dependency

```
 compile('org.springframework:spring-aspects')
```

Comment: ...or equivalent for maven - from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects.  Thanks.