# AspectJ dep not loaded for @Timed annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-aspects

I have exactly same symptoms like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230291/how-to-resolve-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-aspectj-lang-proceedingjoin) and I followed its accepted answer without luck.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Application.java

```
@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
    return new TimedAspect(registry);
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.<init>(TimedAspect.java:73)
    at com..mcs.Application.timedAspect(Application.java:29)
    at com..mcs.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6a83328.CGLIB$timedAspect$1(<generated>)
    at com..mcs.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6a83328$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be4485cd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com..mcs.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6a83328.timedAspect(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
```

It does not make sense to me. The jar aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar contains org\aspectj\lang\ProceedingJoinPoint.class. The class should be loaded.

Similar questions: [ClassNotFoundException - org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162813/classnotfoundexception-org-aspectj-lang-annotation-around)

Update:

The problem was in Intellij IDEA that was not in sync with pom dependencies. A reload in Maven tab helped.

Comment: You also need the `aspectj-rt` dependency.

Comment: The jar aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar contains org\aspectj\lang\ProceedingJoinPoint.class, so rt variant is not neccessary.

Comment: And how are you building your jar?

Comment: mvn install and then run in Idea debugger

Comment: Please add your full pom. Also if you are building your jar then why run it in IDEA? Why not run the main class. Also is this an issue when running the app on the command line or when running it (as a main method) in Idea?

Comment: The problem was in Intellij IDEA that was not in sync with pom dependencies.